# Can I use React Redux in a mobile environment?

Tags: reactjs

Can I use React Redux in a mobile environment? I am trying to distribute it over the web without using React Native

Answer (score 1):

React Redux is device independent and just used for managing state for Javascript apps.
So as long as your "web app with redux" runs on a browser the type of device(tablet,phone,pc) doesn't matter.

Hope this clears your doubt.